# Resize an image in ASPNET VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image

I would like for a user to upload an image to a file in my web application. However, before being saved I want to resize the image to a specified size. I have found code on the Internet to do what I want but I am having trouble adapting to meet my needs. Here is the part I am having trouble with:

```
' Resize Image Before Uploading to DataBase
            Dim imageToBeResized As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
            Dim imageHeight As Integer = imageToBeResized.Height
            Dim imageWidth As Integer = imageToBeResized.Width
            Dim maxHeight As Integer = 240
            Dim maxWidth As Integer = 320
            imageHeight = (imageHeight * maxWidth) / imageWidth
            imageWidth = maxWidth

            If imageHeight > maxHeight Then
                imageWidth = (imageWidth * maxHeight) / imageHeight
                imageHeight = maxHeight
            End If

            Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(imageToBeResized, imageWidth, imageHeight)
            Dim stream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            stream.Position = 0
            Dim image As Byte() = New Byte(stream.Length) {}
            stream.Read(image, 0, image.Length)
```

Rather than upload to a database I want to save the image to a folder in my web application. The problem I have encountered is that VB won't let me save a byte() to a folder. Not sure what I can safely change to adapt for my purposes. Why does it need to be changed to a byte() in the first place?

Comment: why don't you just use Bitmap.Save(filename) or use a stream that writes to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to modify here:

```
 Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(imageToBeResized, imageWidth, imageHeight)
 bitmap.Save("MyFile.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

and remove

```
Dim stream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
stream.Position = 0
Dim image As Byte() = New Byte(stream.Length) {}
stream.Read(image, 0, image.Length)
```

Comment: Thank you! This site is the bomb!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to save it to the database, then it doesn't need to be changed to a byte(). the shift to BYTE() is used to save it as a SQL BLOB.

Basically, instead of diming a MemoryStream at the end, dim a FileStream, and call the BitMap.Save(stream... on the FileStream.

But remember, that the account that's running ASP.NET/IIS will need write permission on the folder where you're trying to save said file.